# How do I add Google OAuth (OpenID Connect) as an IP in Azure ACS?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, acs

*Disclaimer - I am an extreme n00b when it comes to SAML, ACS and OAuth .. and just auth in general. I'm used to Windows Auth and at a push ADFS. I'm afraid you might need to give me the slow "one word a page" version here*

As you are I'm sure aware Google has now deprecated the use of the OpenId 2.0 API for authentication (as of May 19th 2014). This has of course completely broken the "Google" Identity Provider (IP) in Azure Access Control Services (ACS). I basically need to add Google Support back in for a new project and understand it might be a bit more complicated than "click a few buttons".

I have seen a few blogs mention that I might need to "create an STS for the Google Auth, which I then add to ACS as the IP" but they didn't go into any more detail and I honestly don't have any idea how to do this or what it involves. I am happy to write code (I've been writing C# for almost 10 years) but have never done anything like this before.

Can anyone point me at samples / tutorials that will hopefully not go completely over my head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest samples for Google+ are the ones on the [Google+ Github page](https://github.com/googleplus). Check out [the .NET sample](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp), this shows the code flows for OAuth 2.0 using Google's client libraries. There's [a blog post on the key OAuth 2.0 flows in .NET](http://gusclass.com/blog/2014/04/16/how-to-oauth-2-0-flows-using-the-google-net-api-client-libraries-1-7-in-c/) as well.

If you are using MVC, there is [a blog post on integrating OAuth 2.0 with Microsoft's MVC framework](http://peleyal.blogspot.com/2014/01/aspnet-mvc-with-google-openid-and-oauth.html).

Although the samples are not targeted to Azure, I have deployed them to Azure instances without issue. If getting integrated into Azure is shown to be problematic and you think it would be worth it for Google to provide support, [please request a feature in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/).

If you create a plugin, extension, etc that would be useful to other developers, please share with the [Google+ developer community](https://plus.google.com/communities/113527920160449995981).

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback. When you say you have "deployed them to Azure instances" do you mean Azure Access Control Services (ACS) or simply an Azure website / VM ?